# TreeMap not functioning properly in services?

Tags: java, android

I want to build a service and let it work in background silently to handle my data, which is stored in a TreeMap.

Now it seems that I can new an instance of the TreeMap, but couldn't use the put method, but everything is fine when it was inside an activity class. So I couldn't help but suspect it's because I'm using a Service class?

Problematic code:

```
public class MainDataService extends Service
{
    public TreeMap<Integer,Data> DataStorage = new TreeMap<Integer, Data>();

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DataStorage.put(1,"Tommy"); //put is marked in red and cannot be resolved 
                                    //although I imported import java.util.TreeMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Data` ??

Comment: Is a `String` a `Data` subclass ? Obviously not, so here is your problem .

Comment: Side note: [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) is used for types. Variables should be [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (i.e. `dataStorage`)

Comment: As @Berger noted, you/'re defining the `TreeMap` to be of generic type `<Integer, Data>`, so `put` has the signature `put(Integer key, Data value)`, therefore it doesn't resolve for arguments `(Integer, String)`.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin so you are saying Android studio's symbol engine is so powerful that it actually detects the type of the parameter passed in and would refuse if wrong ones were passed? I'll check my code, if that were the case, why doesn't it give a more detailed error message?

Comment: @Berger It's... kinda not like that, you see, as long as I type in "pu", there should be a hint menu popping up listing out all available methods. But the problem is there was this menu, just not with "put" method among them.

Comment: @Michael If I may trouble you with one thing -  you can confirm that both activity and service are mundane classes, one isn't more special than the other right? And my problem most likely isn't caused by attempting to use a method inside a special case of a class?